# Should we write the testng selenium code in java test folder or main folder?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a set of selenium tests which I want to build a jar and run on docker and I am doing a maven based project.

In most of the video tutorials, I see that these tests are written in the test folder.
But in that case, will that build to the jar file and will I be able to execute those?

What is an appropriate folder structure for test selenium project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will based on your pom.xml build configuration.

```
<build>
<finalName>testProject</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <testSource>1.8</testSource>
            <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/libs
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Last section specifically tells maven to include test classes[ Where you write test scripts] and build test jar.

you can execute it by writing,

```
java -cp testProject.jar:testProject-tests.jar:libs/*<other parameters like testNG suite or host etc>
```

When I am using page object framework,I preferred to separate and write Page classes in `src->main` and Test classes in `src-test`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your folder structure as standard maven structure . While packaging create the fat jar using  maven-assembly-plugin which will contain all the classes from main as well as from test folders.

In POM.XML

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Assembly file :

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>fat-tests</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
        <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

> mvn package

You will get the fat jar with all the test dependencies and test classes .

For TestNG Tests : In below example we are running the test having group unit. You can customize it if you wish to send groups from command line

e.g. Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ADD testng-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar /
CMD java -cp testng-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar org.testng.TestNG -testjar testng-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar -groups unit
```